# Python - capturing subprocess exceptions

Tags: python

I'm using os.popen(cmd) to connect to a database with isql. This is in Unix, Python version 2.3.4. I'm trying to implement error handling, and I'm wondering if there's
an efficient way to capture errors/exceptions raised by called subprocesses such as this, without dealing with stderr, etc.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Is this `isql` program a Python script whose output you control?

Comment: no its an executable program on unix

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility210.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All you get is

- whatever comes over the pipe returned from `popen`
- the exit code of the child process when you `pclose` the process.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using subprocess in the following way you should be able to do it like this

```
sql_stdout_stderr = subprocess.Popen(sql_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#communicate returns a tuple
stdout, stderr = sql_stdout_stderr.communicate()
```

This will allow you to return the stdout and error. If the stderr contains anything do error handling if empty do nothing.

Goodluck!

Edit: I just read you dont want to deal with stderr, I really think you should use subprocess where it handles everything neatly for you hopefully that will make things easier to manage.

Comment: hi thanks, unfortunately I'm stuck using python 2.3 which doesn't include the subprocess module. i could get the stderr using os.popen3 but parsing all the various error messages that could come up isn't too practical for my purposes.